# node installation failed on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

can anyone please help me with this issue? I had node installed then I uninstalled and `rm -rf` the file as well following some online suggestions. Then now I am trying to install it like i had done before using `nvm install node`

but now i am getting the following error:

```
Downloading and installing node v15.2.1...
Local cache found: ${NVM_DIR}/.cache/bin/node-v15.2.1-linux-x64/node-v15.2.1-linux-x64.tar.xz
Checksums match! Using existing downloaded archive ${NVM_DIR}/.cache/bin/node-v15.2.1-linux-x64/node-v15.2.1-linux-x64.tar.xz
mv: cannot move '/home/jan/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v15.2.1-linux-x64/files/bin' to '/home/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v15.2.1/bin': Directory not empty
mv: cannot move '/home/jan/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v15.2.1-linux-x64/files/include' to '/home/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v15.2.1/include': Directory not empty
mv: cannot move '/home/jan/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v15.2.1-linux-x64/files/lib' to '/home/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v15.2.1/lib': Directory not empty
mv: cannot move '/home/jan/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v15.2.1-linux-x64/files/share' to '/home/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v15.2.1/share': Directory not empty
Binary download failed, trying source.
Local cache found: ${NVM_DIR}/.cache/src/node-v15.2.1/node-v15.2.1.tar.xz
Checksums match! Using existing downloaded archive ${NVM_DIR}/.cache/src/node-v15.2.1/node-v15.2.1.tar.xz
$>./configure --prefix=/home/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v15.2.1 <
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./configure", line 20, in <module>
    from distutils.spawn import find_executable
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.spawn'
nvm: install v15.2.1 failed!
```

Thanks

Comment: try `nvm uninstall 15.2.1`.

Comment: it says N/A version is not installed...

Answer (score 0):

To get this version, you can use the apt package manager. Refresh your local package index by typing:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install Node.js from the repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

To check which version of Node.js you have installed after these initial steps, type:

```
nodejs -v
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. However, I used the command ```nvm install 14.15.1``` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to uninstall that version of node via nvm before reinstalling it.

```
nvm uninstall 15.2.1
nvm install 15.2.1
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Although I installed the LTS version 14.15.1